# formula to find value from two separate tables and based on values in three tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula for the Party column in Table 3 that will produce its values based on the data contained in Table 1 and Table 2.

1. NumSelect value in Table 3 determines Party value in Table 3.
2. Where NumSelect has "p", it refers to data in Table 1. If no "p" in NumSelect, then it refers to Table 2.
3. Number in NumSelect refers to row number.
4. If the corresponding ShortName has a value, that value should be returned.
5. If the corresponding ShortName is blank, then the corresponding Name should be returned.
6. Uppercase "P" and lowercase "p" in the NumSelect should both point to Table 1.
7. Each table is an Excel Table and its rows may expand or contract.
8. Certain rows in Table 1 and Table 2 may be empty.
9. Formula should not be volatile, not require control+shift+enter to enter the formula, and not require VBA.

Thanks!

Sorry for the bad formatting. I had this question formatted perfectly, but Stack Overflow kept preventing me from posting it because it claimed, "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

**Table 1**

| Name | Gender | ShortName | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grace Turner | F |  | Singer |
| Cadie Crawford | F | Tiger | Fine Artist |
| Paige Johnston | F |  | Archeologist |
| Dexter Payne | M | Klondike | Veterinarian |
| Valeria Barnes | F |  | Chef |
| Florrie Reed | F |  | Lawer |
| Emily Ferguson | F |  | Scientist |
| Sam Hawkins | M | Alpha | Biochemist |
| Savana Ellis | F |  | Cook |

**Table 2**

| Name | Gender | ShortName | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vanessa Cooper | F |  | Producer |
| Jasmine Morris | F | Beta | Baker |
| Evelyn Taylor | F |  | Economist |
| Adelaide Roberts | F |  | Historian |
| Blake Cunningham | M | Lion | Chef |
| Adelaide Harrison | F |  | Chemist |
| Frederick Watson | M |  | Journalist |

**Table 3**

| NumSelect | Party |
| --- | --- |
| p2 | Tiger |
| 3 | Evelyn Taylor |
| P8 | Alpha |
| 2 | Beta |
| 7 | Frederick Watson |
| p7 | Emily Ferguson |

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? If you have Excel 365, you may be able to use Let to shorten the formula, but your mention of control+shift+enter suggests that you haven't.

Comment: I have the latest Excel version. Control+shift+enter is no longer used?

Comment: You no longer need it - Excel 365 with its dynamic arrays uses array entry by default, but you can override it using the @ character https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34.

Comment: Mind blown https://media.tenor.com/Yjx_r38x1aYAAAAd/mind-blown-explosion.gif

Answer (score 3):

### Long Formula

- Your formula has 717 characters, this one has 347.

  ```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("P",[@NumSelect])),
      IF(INDEX(Table1[ShortName],VALUE(RIGHT([@NumSelect],1)))="",
          INDEX(Table1[Name],VALUE(RIGHT([@NumSelect],1))),
          INDEX(Table1[ShortName],VALUE(RIGHT([@NumSelect],1)))),
      IF(INDEX(Table2[ShortName],[@NumSelect])="",
          INDEX(Table2[Name],[@NumSelect]),
          INDEX(Table2[ShortName],[@NumSelect])))
  ```
- A pseudo-code could look like this:

  ```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(A),IF(B="",C,B),IF(D="",E,D))
  ```
- The issue is that `B` (lines 2 & 4) and `D` (lines 5 & 7) are repeated expressions.
- Hopefully, this will help someone to make a major improvement.

**Microsoft 365**

- Using the LET function, you could use the following:

  ```
  =LET(iIndex,[@NumSelect],sIndex,VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(iIndex),"p","")),
      IF(LEN(iIndex)>LEN(sIndex),
          LET(nShort,INDEX(Table1[ShortName],sIndex),nLong,INDEX(Table1[Name],sIndex),
              IF(nShort="",nLong,nShort)),
          LET(nShort,INDEX(Table2[ShortName],sIndex),nLong,INDEX(Table2[Name],sIndex),
              IF(nShort="",nLong,nShort))))
  ```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 but both formulas don't work. They return wrong values. Maybe do the formulas fail to account for empty rows of data? I know the sample data I provided does not have empty rows. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason, at least that's happening on my side. But why would you have empty rows in a table? That's not how tables are used. If you add a column that is always not empty (it could be blank e.g. `=""` or hidden), the formulas should work. The only other option I see is that you could hardcode the ranges in the formulas.

Comment: These tables will be frontends for users to enter data. I want the formula to support empty rows to maximize flexibility and user experience and minimize rigidity and possibilities for failure. If I can program a little extra to burden the user less, such as supporting capital and lowercase "p", it's worth it to me. Would your formula support empty rows of data if you use the FILTER formula as I have done in my solution? I'll try that sometime when I have time. I think that would work better than an additional hidden column workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I figured out the formula. But it's very inefficient. I'm sure someone here could make it a lot shorter and more efficient.

Here it is:

> =IF(
> INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table2[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[Name],Table2[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@NumSelect]),"p",""),3)
> =0,
>
> INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table2[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[Name],Table2[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@NumSelect]),"p",""),1),
>
> INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table2[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@NumSelect],1))="p",1,2),Table1[Name],Table2[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@NumSelect]),"p",""),3)
> )